# Increment value in for loop while reading a file

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

My code looks something like this:

```
for line in `cat fileName`
do

 if [[ $line == "Marker 1" ]]
 then
  while [[ $line != "---" ]]
  do
   #basically I want to read all the data below "Marker 1" till "---"
   echo $line
   ((line++)) #this is wrong

  done
 elif [[ $line == "Marker 2" ]]
 then
  while [[ $line != "---" ]]
  do
   echo $line
   ((line++)) 
  done
 fi
done
```

How do I increment the value of $line when in the while loop? ((line++)) doesn't work

Comment: Do not use `for .. $ (cat file)`, refer Bash Pitfalls, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29

Comment: @Inian thanks for the link! I do agree that for .. $ (cat file) is inefficient. But it doesn't suggest an alternative for going through the contents of the whole file

Comment: @P.P. arithmetic error. That was expected.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using sed

If the goal is to echo all the lines from a line with Marker 1 or Marker 2 to a line with `---`, then that entire shell loop can be replaced with this simple sed command:

```
sed -n '/^Marker [12]$/,/^---$/p' File
```

#### Example

Consider this test file:

```
$ cat File
beginning
Marker 1
one
---
more
Marker 2
two
Two
---
end
```

Now, let's run our command:

```
$ sed -n '/^Marker [12]$/,/^---$/p' File
Marker 1
one
---
Marker 2
two
Two
---
```

#### Using awk

With the same test file:

```
$ awk '/^Marker [12]$/,/^---$/' File
Marker 1
one
---
Marker 2
two
Two
---
```

Answer (score 0):

`((line++))` is for incrementing an integer value.
But the value of `line` in your example is a string.

In fact what you seem to want is get the next line from the file.
You need a different approach for that, and use `while read` instead of a for-loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read_and_print_until_dashes() {
    while read -r line; do
        [[ $line = '---' ]] && break
        echo "$line"
    done
}

while read -r line; do
    if [[ $line = "Marker 1" ]]; then
        echo "$line"
        read_and_print_until_dashes
    elif [[ $line = "Marker 2" ]]; then
        echo "$line"
        read_and_print_until_dashes
    fi
done < file.txt
```